# Automating a new node into Ansible configuration

Tags: ansible

I am trying to automate bootstrapping a new node for instance an EC2 instance into Ansible as a slave node. I have seen some solutions like copying public keys using user-data. Can anyone suggest a more solid approach with an example on how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ansible has two types of nodes

- Master / Control Machines : The node from which ansible is invoked
- Client / Remote Machine : The nodes on which ansible operates

Ansible's primary mode of transport is ssh, using which it applies the playbook to the remote machine. In order for ansible to ssh into the remote machine, ssh has to be already setup between the machine using private/public key authentication preferably.

When it comes to EC2:

1) Every node has a default key with which the instance is launched, and ansible could use this key to ssh, but this considered insecure / not a best pratice.

2) A key has to present in the client node, with which ansible can authenticate successfully, and the most preferred way is to pull the keys using user-data from a restricted S3 bucket.